# what is the difference between (.*js$) and .*(js)$

Tags: python, regex, tornado

I'm using tornado to build a server. It is based on python and I need to do as below:

```
application.add_handlers(r"^(www).*",[
    (r"/(.*js$)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'static/'}),
    (r"/(.*xml$)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'static/'}),
    (r"/(.*css$)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'static/'}),
    (r"/(.*jpg$)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'static/'}),
    (r"/(.*png$)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'static/'}),
    (r"/(.*ico$)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'static/'}),
    (r"/(.*html$)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'static/'}),

    (r"/$", IndexHandler),
])
```

The code above is about to tell a http request the location of resource that it requests. So here I tell a http request that it can get js, xml, css, jpg, png, ico and html files under the path `./static/`.

It does work well but I don't quite understand the regex part.
As you see `r"/(.*js$)"` is a regex, which is to match a http request. If the http request is looking for a js file, the first regex will be matched but I dont' know how.

As my understanding, if I want to match a js file, I need to make a regex like this: `r"/.*(js)$"`, which means that the files ending with `js`. I tried but it doesn't work.

So why does `(.*js$)` work? Doesn't it mean that files ending with one letter `s` instead of `js`? What is the difference between `.*(js)$` and `(.*js$)`? Moreover, what id the difference between `^.*abc$`, `.*abc$`, `^.*abc`, `.*(abc)$`, `^.*(abc)`?

I must misunderstand or can't understand some rules about `()`, `^` and `$` in regex.

Comment: What you're asking is really a tutorial on regex. They exist online already: [in general](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), [about anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), [about groups and captures](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'why does (.*js$) work?`

Above regex match anything that ends with `js` and not only file with extension `js`
See this regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DkxtVb/1) with explanation.

To match a file that has the `js` extension you need the following regex

```
(.*\.js$)
```

Comment: Good catch. That seems to be a problem with the supposedly working version as well.

Comment: @Yves: Where did you get that routing table from? The over-eager matching should be fixed there.

Answer (score 1):

Round brackets **()** denote capture group.
If for instance your address is http://www.example.com/something.js
`r"/(.*js$)"` will match and capture **www.example.com/something.js**
`r"/.*(js)$"` will also match, but will only capture **js**

I don't know what tornado is, but I'm assuming it does something with the captured address, so if you don't get the whole thing it wont work even though the regex matches. For your other questions, try looking [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) for more info on basic regex meanings

Comment: Thanks a lot. Tornado is a new framework to build a web server. It is just like tomcat but very very light and easy to learn.

Comment: Note that it matters whether the `.*` is inside the parentheses, but it doesn't matter (in this example) whether or not the `$` is. `$` is a "zero-width match" in regex terms, so it doesn't contribute anything to the capturing group. In more complicated cases it might make a difference where the `$` is (for example, if `|` is used).

Answer (score 0):

The part between the `()` is what is returned as a captured group.

Your alternative pattern only returns "js", which is not so useful to find the static resource for the URL. The original returned the complete path (minus the leading slash).

So yes, your pattern also matches the URL, but it does not return a path  that resolves to any of your static resources (try creating a file called `static/js` and see if you get that one instead).